# visual studio 2010 user macros property sheet

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I defined some "user macros" (name/value pair) in property pages(property manager - choose/add project property sheet). But **it is project specific** property sheet, now **I want it to be global**, so I could use my macro with **any solution/project**(I only need to define some name/value pairs like "libs_to_link = lib1.lib;lib2.lib")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new Property Sheet.  In the Property Manager, select one of your Projects, then click on the icon to Add New Project Property Sheet.  This will create a .props file you name.  Set your macros in that sheet.  Then add the property sheet to all the other Projects you want to export the macro to, and click on the Add Existing Property Sheet icon to select the file you just made.  You will now have your macro available to all Projects.